# Writing JUnit test cases for a Spring Boot Service Application with autowired components

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am attempting to write JUnit test cases for a spring service application that I created. I've finished smoke testing the application and am looking to write a collection of unit tests moving forward.

I am starting with testing the service layer. I am running into an issue with my @AutoWired components, including my DAO object. When running the Spring application itself, everything works fine. However, when running my JUnit tests they do not autowire and remain null, causing NPEs. Here is a skeleton of what I am working with:

Service file:

```
@Component
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebService{

@Autowired
WebDAO webDAO;

@Override
public List<String> getItems(){
    List<String> items = webDAO.getItems();
    /*
     * some filtering/actions done here
    */ 
    return items;
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTests{
    private WebService service;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.service = new WebServiceImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void getItemsTest(){
        List<String> items = this.service.getItems();
        assertNotNull(items);
    }
}
```

When running this test I get an NPE from webDAO. It does not get autowired like it would normally in the spring boot startup. I am new to working Spring so I am not sure the best way to proceed. I assume this is not getting autowired because I am not starting the application as it would be normally, but am instantiating the class directly.

My only possible thought would be to create a getter/setter for the dao here for the sole purpose of testing; however I would have to do that for every autowired field used and Idk if it would have any unwanted results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You autowire the component under test, into the test.

You are creating the component outside of the Spring Container thus it has no knowledge of that component.

```
  private WebService service;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.service = new WebServiceImpl();
    }
```

Should just be

```
@Autowired
private WebService service;
```

Comment: ah, rookie mistake. thank you for taking the time to answer!